# Angular 2 directive change detection, directive not updating

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app that displays a number. The number can be negative or positive. If the value is negative I am setting the font color to red. I am doing this via a directive. This number is constantly updated via an emitter.

The problem I am having is when the value changes from a negative to positive value. The directive isn't picking up this change and is very slow to run, ie the color is not updating. I have to click anywhere on the screen and then the font color changes. 
I don't think change detection is happening when I need it to.

How do I make this directive update at the same time the underlying value does?

My directive looks like this...

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[negativeValueStyle]' })
export class NegativeValueStyleDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterContentChecked() {

        if (this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML < 0)
            this.el.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';
        else
            this.el.nativeElement.style.color = 'black';
    }
}
```

It is being applied to the UI like this...

```
<td negativeValueStyle>{{data.return | number: '1.2-2'}}%</td>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh dear, that looks like a wrong approach to use angular and it's capabilities. I believe a better approach would be to use the binding on `style.color` in combination with a value passed through the `negativeValueStyle` directive:

> untested code ahead

```
@Directive({ selector: '[negativeValueStyle]' })
export class NegativeValueStyleDirective {

    @Input('negativeValueStyle')
    public value: number;

    @HostBinding('style.color')
    public get color(): string {
       return this.value < 0 ? 'red' : 'black';
    }

    @HostBinding('innerHtml')
    public get innerHtml(): string {
       return this.value + '%';
    }
}
```

you can then use this directive like this:

```
<td [negativeValueStyle]="data.return | number: '1.2-2'"></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way of doing things. I was copying the Ng2 website example on setting the css style but I like this better. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#write-directive